# Google chrome doesnt render 100% height of body element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, height

I have problem with Google Chrome - it doesn't make body element 100% height.

In my sample webpages, when you have 100% zoom and hover menu element (for example "O nás", I change `background-color` of body element, but in Chrome on the bottom of page stay white color.

Sample is here: http://kovar_sandbox.pakultura.cz/ultrafun/index.php?id=video

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use a lot of `position:absolute` on your page.
Position absolute doesn't change the height of non-positioned elements.
Your body isn't positioned, so it's height won't be 'correct'.
To fix it, simply make the body `position:relative`

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
```